# CakePHP l10n default locale

Tags: cakephp, localization

We are struggling with a l10n problem in cakePHP. It seems that the default language is picked up from what is sent by the browser's user agent. Is there a way to override this option, using a setting in core.php ?

Thanks

Regards
Gabriel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is about localization (l10n).

I think that the cookbook can help you : http://book.cakephp.org/view/1230/Localization-in-CakePHP

Regards